# Optimizing isinstance() usage in Python

Tags: python, optimization

I profiled a Python script that uses the 3rd party unicodecsv library.  A large part of the time was spent in the [_stringify function shown here](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv/blob/c5d8ae68758dd48d8a776214080caa88bc036644/unicodecsv/__init__.py#L35).  Does anyone have any suggestions on how this small loop can be optimized or is this about as good as you'll get in Python?  I tried something dumb involving grabbing the mro() tuple and searching through that each time manually but it wasn't even close to an improvement.

Here's the code for reference:

```
def _stringify(s, encoding, errors):
    if s is None:
        return ''
    if isinstance(s, unicode):
        return s.encode(encoding, errors)
    elif isinstance(s, (int , float)):
        pass #let csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC do its thing.
    elif not isinstance(s, str):
        s=str(s)
    return s
```

Here's something to bootstrap your testing of unicodecsv.  Yes, I am producing CSVs with around 3000-4000 columns.

```
import unicodecsv

import random
import StringIO
import cProfile
import datetime

# roughly the size of the data set I was working with
# still very big, a couple hundred megs of ram

data = []
for _ in xrange(5000):
    row = []
    for __ in xrange(4000):
        row.append(random.randint(0,15000))
    data.append(row)

fd = StringIO.StringIO()

writer = unicodecsv.writer(fd, encoding="utf-8")

p = cProfile.Profile()

n = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

p.enable()
for row in data:
    writer.writerow(row)
p.disable()

print datetime.datetime.utcnow() - n, 'total time'

p.dump_stats('profile_output')
```

Comment: What makes you think the time was spent in `isinstance` and not either encoding or converting to `str`?

Comment: Good question DSM.  My CSV data in the profiled script were lists of plain integer types, there were no objects or any other funny business at all.

Comment: @ldrg: if your data is all integers, then you can easily check whether the profiler is right. Replace the contents of the function with just `return s`, since that's what it does in the only case that actually happens. If that doesn't speed things up then there is no conceivable optimization to this function that would :-)

Comment: Steve: yes, it speeds it up, overall time down to 6 seconds from 19 on the bootstrap script I've added above.

Comment: What do you need `unicodecsv` for? Does the `csv` module not suffice? Could you get away with pre-encoding your strings and putting them through the built-in `csv` module?

Comment: All I can really think is to move the check that actually succeeds to the top of the function. I'm very surprised that a couple of calls to `isinstance` is so slow compared with generating the CSV data.

Comment: ... Unless something a bit odd is happening, like the `isinstance` checks are triggering a bunch of cache misses on your 200MB of data that wouldn't otherwise happen.

Comment: neon: In my case I could do all the encoding myself, but for anyone looking to handle types in the general case will wind up reimplementing this function.